# How to change single line item's style in a list?

Tags: html, css, list

I'm certain this is a simple problem with a simple answer, but i don't have much experience working with CSS and Googling is just directing me to answers for different CSS/list questions. so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

specifically, i'd like to change the font color of a single item (`id="ttm_nav_header_sale"`) in an unordered list. but am having trouble with the cascading styles.

HTML as follows:

```
<div id="ttm_nav_header">
<ul>
    {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}
        {% if link.title == "Drums" or link.title == "Accessories" %}
            <li rel="nav_{{ link.title }}"><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/</li>
        {% elsif link.title == "Sale" %} 
            <li id="tmm_nav_header_sale" ><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

css:

```
#ttm_nav_header ul li a:link, #ttm_nav_header ul li a:visited, #ttm_nav_sub ul li a:link, #ttm_nav_sub ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

#ttm_nav_header ul li a:hover, #ttm_nav_sub ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#229fdb;
}

/* !!! HERE */
#tmm_nav_header_sale {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? The CSS should work. Please post your generated HTML.

Comment: This isn't HTML; please post the **final** HTML

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the link colour in which case, you'll need to target the `a`

```
#ttm_nav_header ul li#tmm_nav_header_sale a {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: red;
}
```

EDIT:

The specificity of the link needs to be greater than the preceding definitions so the above should work

http://jsfiddle.net/w7Qn9/

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a specificity problem, i.e. the css classes you've defined earlier in your style sheet have taken precedence over the link you want to target with a different style.

Here's a better structure:

```
#ttm_nav_header a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}

#ttm_nav_header a:hover, #ttm_nav_sub a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#229fdb;
}

/* !!! HERE */
#ttm_nav_header #tmm_nav_header_sale a {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: red;
}
```